# Visual Studio doesn't show errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio

All works fine, but from some moment Visual Studio stops to show me the errors list. I am trying to run a project and in compilation I got such pop up

[image]

I click `No`, and usually at bottom I can see list of errors, but now don't. Now it looks like this

[image]

How to fix it? I have already tried to restart PC as well as Visual Studio, but nothing help. I can't track where I am getting an errors.

Comment: Look into Output window.

Comment: Click on the ```Build + Intellisense``` combo box and switch to ```Build only```. That might help.

Answer (score 2):

sometimes it happen also to me ... you have to carefully check you `OUTPUT WINDOWS`

[image]

also i suggest to you to install a VS plugins called `vscoloroutput` which color your ouput windows with red and green so you can easly check where the error is.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

You might need to check the output instead.

I had stumbled upon a time where I had my build error displayed in Output for some reasons.